# C++ temporary string lifetime

Tags: c++, string, temporary

Apologies as I know similar-looking questions exist, but I'm still not totally clear. Is the following safe?

```
void copyStr(const char* s)
{
    strcpy(otherVar, s);
}

std::string getStr()
{
    return "foo";
}

main()
{
    copyStr(getStr().c_str());
}
```

A temporary std::string will store the return from getStr(), but will it live long enough for me to copy its C-string elsewhere? Or must I explicitly keep a variable for it, eg

```
std::string temp = getStr();
copyStr(temp.c_str());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. The temporary from `getStr` lives to the end of the full expression it appears in. That full expression is the `copyStr` call, so it must return before the temporary  from `getStr` is destroyed. That's more than enough for you.

Comment: As per my understanding , for this case , a string object is created from the string  literal "foo" and is returned (through copy ellision may be) and when we say getStr().c_str() , it may not refer to the exact string literal. Is that correct?

Comment: @bsguru: Correct. Theoretically the C++ Standard allows "as-if" optimizations, but in practice that is still infeasible for this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

A temporary variable lives until the end of the full expression. So, in your example,

```
copyStr(getStr().c_str());
```

`getStr()`’s return value will live until the end of `copyStr`. It is therefore safe to access its value inside `copyStr`. Your code is potentially still unsafe, of course, because it doesn’t test that the buffer is big enough to hold the string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a temporary variable and assign to it the return result:

```
...
{
  std::string tmp = getStr();
  //tmp live
  ...
}
//tmp dead
...
```

A temporary var must have a name, and will live in the scope where it has been declared in.

**Edit**: it is safe, you pass it by copied value (your edit was heavy, and nullified my above answer. The above answer concern the first revision)

`copyStr(getStr().c_str());` will pass the rvalue to copyStr()

Comment: Yep, I mixed L and Rvalue sorry. Edited

Comment: That’s not what I meant, the rest is wrong as well: “a temporary must have a name” – no, on the contrary: a temporary *cannot* have a name.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I said "Edit: question nullified my above answer"
Look at the first revision, before he edited. He has written std::string getStr();

Comment: Well, the answer already starts with "you have to declare a temporary variable" - they're not declared either. But Konrad and I use the formal term _temporary_ as defined in the ISO standard, and obviously this answer uses a (confusing) different meaning.

Comment: I understand it as the same formal term as you, but here obviously the OP was refering to the var he named `temp`. For clarification sake I just used the term temporary, same confusing meaning as in the question. Check revision 0 of the question and re read my answer, and maybe reconsider your downvote.